# Error [ERR_HTTP_HEADERS_SENT]: Cannot set headers after they are sent to the client | NodeJS ExpressJS MySQL

Tags: node.js, express, post

I dont know what to say, i think code says everything. i just want to render something and this error appears, but i dont know why. I tried so many solutions from stackoverflow, and others that i couldn't count them all. Im using mysql2 lib. Please help.

```js
router.get("/:link", function(req, res){
  connection.query(
    "SELECT * FROM yourshort WHERE link = '" + req.params.link + "'",
    function (err, result, rows, fields){
      Object.keys(result).forEach(function(key) {
        var row = result[key];
        console.log(row.link)
        if(row.link = req.params.link) {
          res.send(row.link + row.views + rows.created)
          return;
        } else {
          res.send("URL does not exist")
          return;
        }
      }); 
  });
});
```

Comment: It is because you are calling `res.send()` multiple times in a loop.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

just because you send it in foreach you get that error .

do you want to send it just one time and first item of db ? if yes use this :

```
router.get("/:link", function (req, res) {
var i = 0;
connection.query(
    "SELECT * FROM yourshort WHERE link = '" + req.params.link + "'",
    function (err, result, rows, fields) {
        Object.keys(result).forEach(function (key) {
            var row = result[key];
            console.log(row.link)
            if (row.link = req.params.link) {
                if (i === 0) {
                    res.send(row.link + row.views + rows.created)
                    i = 1;
                }
            } else {
                if (i === 0) {
                    res.send("URL does not exist")
                    i = 1;
                }
            }
        });
    });
```

});

Comment: Thanks for help, but URL does not exist does not work, it loads forever.

Answer (score 0):

A service that sends your data. You run into problems when you try to return your data in a loop. The good thing about this is to come back after you get all the result you will get from the loop. You can use asynchronous structure for this. Maybe you can try this.

```
router.get("/:link", (req, res) => {
  let myObject = {};

  connection.query(
    "SELECT * FROM yourshort WHERE link = '" + req.params.link + "'",
    async(err, result, rows, fields) => {
      await Object.keys(result).forEach(function(key) {
        var row = result[key];
        if(row.link = req.params.link) {
          myObject[key] = {link: row.link, views: row.views, created: rows.created} 
          return;
        } else {
          myObject['error'] = 'URL does not exist';
          return;
        }
      }); 

      await res.send(myObject);
  });


});
```